# How get the priority in regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have a wrong regex

```
([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9]*\.)
```

I need to accept strings like:

- `a-b.`
- `ab.`
- `a.`

But i am not needing in this string - `a-.`

What should I change?

Comment: Try to debug it on regex101

Comment: Can you explain in plain English what the regex rule is?

Comment: `[A-Za-z0-9](?:-[A-Za-z0-9\-])*[A-Za-z0-9]*\.`

Answer (score 1):

```
[A-Za-z0-9]+\.|[A-Za-z0-9]+-?[A-Za-z0-9]\.
```

The idea is:

- `-?` - optional dash
- `\.` - escaped dot, to match literal dot
- `|` - alternation (one or the other)
- `x+` - one or more repetitions, equivalent to `xx*`

If you don't mind matching underscores too, you can use the [word character set](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_wordchar.asp):

```
\w+\.|\w+-?\w\.
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/xO9vG2/2)

Comment: I have understood the idea. Nice way!=) Thank U very much from Russia)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this by using an optional group.

```
"(?i)[A-Z0-9](?:-?[A-Z0-9]+)*\\."
```

- `(?i)` flag for caseless matching.
- `[A-Z0-9]` one alphanumeric character
- `(?:-?[A-Z0-9]+)*` any amount of [`(?:`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group) an optional hyphen followed by one or more alnum `)`
- `\.` literal dot

[See demo at Regexplanet](http://fiddle.re/p7ehp6) (click Java)

Comment: Thank U a lot. What does mean '?:'  ?

Comment: @E.Simchuk Welcome! `(?:` starts a [non capture group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group).

Comment: @E.Simchuk, `(?:)` is basically the same as `()`, it just doesn't capture the group. It doesn't make a difference as far as matching goes.

Answer (score 1):

This works for your test cases:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/hWeSTergOs).